# How can an addition operator for a C++ class container be optimized?

Tags: c++, class, optimization, operator-keyword, addition

consider

```
 class abc
   {
     public:
     map<int,double> data;

     abc(map<int,double> && in):data(std::move(in)){}
     abc operator + (const abc & in)
     {
     auto tmp = data;
       for( auto & itr : in.data)
          tmp[itr.first] += itr.second;
      return abc(std::move(tmp));
     }
   };
```

I guess a better implementation could be

```
     abc operator + (const abc & in)
     {
      auto &tmp1 = (data.size() > in.data.size() ? data : in.data);
      auto &tmp2 = (data.size() > in.data.size() ? in.data : data);
      auto tmp = tmp1;
       for( auto & itr : tmp2)
          tmp[itr.first] += itr.second;
      return abc(std::move(tmp));
     }
```

What I would like to achieve is that, if I have a statement, for example,

```
    S = A+B+C+D+E
```

and suppose `B` , `C` and `D` are empty the cost should be same as

```
   S = A+E
```

Essentially I do not want to incur cost if `abc` type is zero. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Yes, you take advantage of the fact that temporaries are not destroyed until the end of a full expression. So you make `operator + (..., ...)` return a proxy object that simply references the objects. Let the proxies be "concat-able" with themselves and your object by `operator + (..., ...)`. On the final assignment from the last created proxy, you do the addition in one swoop from all that the proxies have linked...

Comment: @WhiZTim could you provide illustration or link to show this technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will do better with:

```
 abc operator + (abc lhs, const abc& rhs)   // Note 'lhs' by value.
 {
     for(const auto & val : rhs.data)
         lhs.data[val.first] += val.second;
     return lhs;                                  // Rely on NRVO 
 }
```

The reason to prefer taking the argument by value, is that if it is a temporary (like, for instance, the result of `A + B`) then there will be no need for a copy.  The compiler can just pass the temporary directly.

**Edit**
A proxy as suggested by [WhiZTiM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1621391/whiztim) will be much more efficient as it defers everything to the end.  It relies on the fact that temporaries are not destroyed until the end of the full expression.

```
struct Proxy
{
    std::vector<const abc*> values;

    operator abc() {
        assert(values.size() > 2);
        abc result = *(values.back());  // Can't avoid one copy.
        values.pop_back();
        for (const auto& v : values)
            for (const auto& key_value : v->data)
                result.data[key_value.first] += key_value.second;

        return result;
     }
};

Proxy operator +(const abc &lhs, const abc& rhs) {
    Proxy result;
    result.values.push_back(&lhs);
    result.values.push_back(&rhs);
    return result;
}

Proxy operator +(Proxy lhs, const abc& rhs) {
    lhs.values.push_back(&rhs);
}
Proxy operator +(const abc& lhs, Proxy rhs) {
    rhs.values.push_back(&lhs);
}
Proxy operator +(Proxy lhs, const Proxy& rhs) {
    // implementation left as an exercise for the reader.
}
```

Note: Above not exposed to a compiler.

Comment: does NRVO happen on function argument?

Comment: Ah.  Good point.  Possibly not.  Worth inspecting the output though

Comment: would `std::move` at the return be a better optimization?

Comment: @user6386155 : Try it with your compiler and see what assembly it generates.  ... but generating a proxy as WhiZTiM suggests will be much faster anyway.

Comment: Ok but I do not understand how to implement his comment.. I have asked him for illustration or link for such technique

Comment: I tested and found that 'abc result = *(values.back()); ' and 'return result;' lines in 'operator abc' taking most of the time. Do you have suggestion on improvements on these?

Comment: I don't see how to avoid the copy implied by `*(values.back())`.  You could *try* replacing the .back and pop_back lines with just `abc result;`, and add everything to the (initially empty) result - in fact that might be cleaner anyway.  As to the `return abc;` being expensive - does `abc` have a non-throwing move constructor?  That might help (although I would have *expected* it to be subject to NRVO).

Comment: Non-throwing move constructor helps! (I am on VS2012)